# Выборка с бд Mysql с динамическим именем таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Нужно сделать выборку с бд при это название таблицы, откуда делается выборка, образуется исходя из префикса таблицы и данных которые извлекаются из таблицы.

Таблицы: Сайты, Чаты и Чат_ID (таблицы с перепиской).

Мне надо получить id сайта и количество непрочитанных у этого сайта.
Делаю так:

```
SELECT
  s.id AS id,
 (SELECT
   COUNT(*)
  FROM
    КАК ПОЛУЧИТЬ ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ? AS ch
  WHERE
    ch.chat_id = c.id AND
    status = 0 AND
    type = 'CLIENT'
  ) AS unread
FROM
  site AS s
  LEFT JOIN chat AS c ON
    c.site_id = s.id AND
    c.operator_id = s.user_id
WHERE
  s.user_id = 1;
```

Название таблицы состоит из префикса и id сайта - chat_1.

Может это и не правильно - не кидайте тапкапи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не правильно. Вместо набора таблиц `Чат_ID` вам нужна одна таблица `Переписки`. А в эту таблицу вы добавите поле `Чат_ID`

Comment: У меня сайтов может быть очень много и при этом все равно писать чаты всех сайтов в одну таблицу?

Comment: @Tsyklop Именно так. Пусть хоть тысяча сайтов будет.

Comment: Ну вот я запрос написал в одну строку, а Вы как-то отформатировали его в нормальный вид. Как или чем?